# qTranslate is too slow when plugin is activated in wordpress

Tags: qtranslate

I have problem with qTranslate plugin(the latest one) in wordpress 3.8.1.
When qtranslate activate. the web site is too slow. 
I have checked the speed with pingdom. It was 1.0 sec to show the front page without qtranslate, but it is more than 5 sec with qtranslate.

Anyone who helps me with this issues?

Thanks in advance.

Best Wishes.

Jayden

Comment: This is off-topic. Stack Overflow is about coding. Try http:/superuser.com or http://serverfault.com.